# The multiplication table of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_8)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the Group $\mathbb{Z}_8$

I'm trying to figure out the multiplication table of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_8)$.

I know the generators of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ are (1,3,5,7). I have been told that these are equally the generators of $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_8)$.

I am familiar with Cayley tables, so I need to actually prove what the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ are and then apply them to that format. I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I was talking about the group $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Comment: Since ${\bf Z}_8$ is cyclic, any automorphism is determined by the image of any one generator, say, the image of $1$. And the image of $1$ msut be a generator, and can be any generator. That should help you answer all your questions.

Comment: Z8 is cyclic, meaning it's automorphic group will be the Klein 4 group? Cyclic itself is very useful knowledge, so ty.

Comment: I'm not sure how you get from ${\bf Z}_8$ being cyclic to its automorphism group being Klein-$4$.

Comment: Z8 being finite cyclic group gave me an idea of how to use its nature. The automorphism group is cyclic iff order n is 2,4, a power of an odd prime, or twice a power of an odd prime. Hence I can look at the generators of Aut(Z8) also and work from there.

Answer (score 2):

An endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is uniquely determined by where it sends a generator. In other words, one can look at where the generator 1 is sent. If you want your function to be to be an automorphism, then the function must map 1 to another generator. The generators are all numbers comprime to 8. With this list of all automorphisms, one can start composing to unravel the structure. Also there are only two groups of order 4, up to isomorphism.

Comment: Reminds me of my earlier comment on the question.